# TouchableOpacity behaves weird

Tags: reactjs, react-native, touchableopacity

```
    <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          width: BannerWidth,
          height: (deviceHeight * 25) / 100,
          marginBottom: 40,
          backgroundColor: theme.colors.batiLacivert,
        }}>   
         <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Actions.portfoy()}>
          <View
            style={{
              width: 48,
              height: 60,
              left: 0,
              top: 50,
            }}>
            <Image
              style={{
                width: 48,
                height: 60,
                left: 40,
                bottom: -30,
                position: 'absolute',
              }}
              source={require('../../assets/yuzdeler/0yuzde_yeni.png')}
            />
            <Text
              style={{
                position: 'absolute',
                color: 'black',
                left: 47,
                bottom: 0,
                fontSize: 20,
              }}>
              %{this.state.anasayfaBilgiler.Performans}
            </Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
```

I have this code in my project. I use `position: absolute` to position my shield icon on a `View`, and I wrapped it into a `TouchableOpacity` to press it and go to another page. But when I press on the shield, Nothing happens, But when I press the View on the background, It applies the code, it should have done it on the shield...How can I fix this?

**Edit: Now it works when the Shield icon on the background View, but when I position it in the bottom, the overflow area of the icon doesnt work just upper half takes the click. I need it to work all over the image**

This area -with blue color - doesn't click:

[image: This area doesn't click]

Comment: I've got this problem before and solve it by adding a `style` prop to `TouchableOpacity` where you should add position. try to add `style={{ position: 'absolute', width: 48, height: 60,  left: 0, top: 50, }}` to `TouchableOpacity`

Comment: I did it first but didn't work

Comment: and you have to delete `position: 'absolute'` from Image and Text component

Comment: @MahdiN When I did this, the problem about Touchable disappears, I mean onPress for Touchable does not work as intended, but onPress for shield icon doesn't work as well

Comment: @MahdiN It doesn't work even deleting positions on text and Image. Sometimes works sometimes not I didn't understand...

Comment: I think that I wasn't clear enough with my explication I will post an answer with code to more explain my idea

Comment: @MahdiN Ok, thanks

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have imported `TouchableOpacity` from `react-native` and not `react-native-gesture-handler`

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to fix style (height, width, position: 'absolute', top, left) only to `TouchableOpacity` component. Because if you set for example `top: 50` to a child component this child will be under the touchableOpacity component by 50 and your onPress function will be fired only if you press the top of your component by 50. You just need position absolute on Text component because it should be on the Image.

```
<View
  style={{
    flex: 1,
    width: BannerWidth,
    height: (deviceHeight * 25) / 100,
    marginBottom: 40,
    backgroundColor: theme.colors.batiLacivert,
  }}
>
  <TouchableOpacity style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 50, left: 40 }} onPress={() => Actions.portfoy()}>
    <View
      style={{
        width: 48,
        height: 60,
      }}
    >
      <Image
        style={{
          width: 48,
          height: 60,
        }}
        source={require('../../assets/yuzdeler/0yuzde_yeni.png')}
      />
      <Text
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          color: 'black',
          fontSize: 20,
        }}
      >
          %
        {this.state.anasayfaBilgiler.Performans}
      </Text>
    </View>
  </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

Hope I was clear.

Comment: The problem is, When I did it as you said, it is ok unless I position the Shield to the bottom where half of it overflows the background View. In this position, only half of the Shield icon takes the onPress, the bottom half doesn't work. I need it to fully functional, wherever you clicked it should work

Comment: Try to add `zIndex: 100` to style in `TouchableOpacity`

Comment: Sorry that it didn't worked for you. As long as I know, order of components matter when you set position absolute, can you try to move the shield code to the end of your render function after all other components code

Comment: I now deleted all the code and do it again with a clean approach, now it is ok Thanks you very much

Comment: I needed to adjust the `height` of the `TouchableOpacity` to somehow cover the children. Thanks.